# Чи має слово «попередити» значення схоже на «запобігти»

Tags: значення-слів

Вчора прочитав таку рекламу в метро:

> Швидко втамує нежіть і допоможе попередити гайморит.

Для мене це прозвучало як наче гаймориту щось повідомлять, попередять про щось. Чи має слово «попередити» схоже до значення слова «запобігти», чи потрібно вживати якесь інше слово?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На попередити СУМ-11 пропонує дивитись [попереджати](http://sum.in.ua/s/poperedzhaty), де ми в свою чергу знаходимо в пунктах 2 і 3:

> 2. Своєчасними заходами **запобігати** здійсненню або виникненню чого-небудь, перев. небажаного. Розумне поєднання праці з активним
>      відпочинком на основі гігієнічних вимог попереджує виникнення
>      втомлюваності *(Мистецтво, 5, 1955, 44);* Горничну, обстригши і
>      вимазавши голову дьогтем, — вигнали з двору. Те ждало в дворі Мотрю,
>      та Мотря попередила. Вона так укоськала пана, що ще Йосипенкові
>      дісталося *(Панас Мирний, IV, 1955, 182).*
> 3. Передувати чому-небудь. Висока полонина над селом помалу просвітлюється тим слабим, червоним світлом, що попереджає світ сонця
>      (Іван Франко, III, 1950, 82); Всі ринуть туди, де хмарою в'ється
>      чорний дим, попереджаючи хвилі полум'я... *(Михайло Коцюбинський, I,
>      1955, 120);*
>      //  кого. Здійснювати що-небудь раніше від когось.
>      Прокуратор кидається піддержувати її, але Меценат попереджає його,
>      надівши Нерісі намистд на шию і тим самим рухом піддержавши її (Леся
>      Українка, III, 1952, 464); — Ми починаємо бій о шостій ранку —
>      попередимо ворога на дві години *(Юрій Яновський, I, 1958, 162);*
>      // кого. Здійснювати рух, яку-небудь дію швидше від когось; **випереджати**.
>      То вона швиденько йде, нас попереджаючи, то вона одстане... (Марко
>      Вовчок, I, 1955, 191); Починаються ви передки. Скакать мусили до шести
>      верстов. Хто попередить, той бере коня *(Збірник про Кропивницького,
>      1955, 10);*
>      //  що. Розвиватися швидше від чого-небудь. Тепер так
>      дійсність переплетена з казкою, так попередила її, що всякого
>      сподіватись можна... *(Дніпрова Чайка, Тв., 1960, 107);*
>      //  З'являтися
>      швидко, блискавично, один поперед одного. Ціле море спогадів налинуло
>      до мене, один одного попереджаючи *(Степан Васильченко, I, 1959, 376);*
>      //  Пришвидшувати здійснення чого-небудь. От і тепер, для того
>      проблематичного загального добра, він силоміць попередив неминуче,
>      правда, для Замфіра лихо, скривдив цілу родину *(Михайло Коцюбинський,
>      I, 1955, 224).*

Отже, тут можна тлумачити в значеннях **запобігти** і **випередити**.